# margins, phone and tablet, multiple fragments, android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an application I'm designing for phone and tablet devices. The spacing on the tablet is not the desired effect when I use weight attributes in my `XML-layout` because they stretch too far on the tablet.

Example - on the Phone it looks like this

-5dp------*Frag1*------5dp-

-5dp------*Frag2*------5dp-

-5dp-(-*T1*-)(---*T2*--)-5dp-

So it's nice and looks clean with t1 having a `weight` of 1 and t2 having a `weight` of 2. On the Tablet there is a third fragment being inflated and it looks like this

---*Frag1*---|-------------------------------*Frag3*-------------------------------

---*Frag2*---|-(*Text1*---------)------------(-----*Text2*------------------------)-

Now I know this is because its T1 = `weight` 1 which is 33% of the screen and T2 = `weight` 2 taking up 66% of the screen. **My question: is there any way to somehow center, or push the two elements together so they don't look stretched and have big empty spaces between them? So they look like this?**

---*Frag1*---|-------------------------------*Frag3*-------------------------------

---*Frag2*---|--------(*Text1*---------)-(-----*Text2*--------------------)---------

I tried setting `layout-margins` for left and right in my `XML` but it did nothing

I wouldn't mind making a completely different layout for Tablets but this thing is going to have a lot of `fragments` (50-100) and making doubles each one individually will be extremely time consuming and a huge headache. I would love if there was something I could do to the `fragment` container to manipulate the appearance the way I want. As in setting margins etc.

Comment: @manjusg could you expand on that answer? Do you mean as in for the fragment container? I ask because I rarely if ever use relative layouts and the problem is my "weight" attributes. I'm not sure if they even work in relative layouts

Comment: You'll need different layouts. Try wrapping the current `Linearlayout`(which will have width set to `wrap_content`) in another layout(with the width set to fill_parent(that is what you're using for the current `LinearLayout`, right?)) and set the `android:gravity="center"` on that layout.

Comment: @Luksprog I am using Linear, correct. So width fill parent, gravity center, not layout gravity. I'll try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to fix this is giving the fragment containers weight values. The end result was that the fragment on the left stretched a little and made the one on the right adjust

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/store_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The end result looked something like this with a 33%/66% ratio on the screen.

--*Frag1*--|----*-Frag3*-----|

--*Frag2*--|

Not exactly what I was looking for but it worked relatively well. If anyone else has a better solution I'll accept it. Thanks!